# VSCode show large python tests diff

Tags: python, unit-testing, visual-studio-code

I'm running a python test suite and would like to visually see the difference between the expected and the actual result, like in IntelliJ "Click to see the difference" ... Is there such a feature?

Comment: If you're running it with the vscode test explorer, then you can go to the test and it should show a red line that you can click.

Comment: I had submitted a [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18781) on GitHub.